# ngx-leaflet does not detect layer changes through a service (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I am running Angular 6 and I want to dynamically add a layer to a leaflet map, but I can't detect changes in leafletLayers if the layers are modified from another component. Everything works fine if the layer changes are performed from  `map.component` but it doesn't work if I make changes from outside:

Example:

**map.component.ts**

```
layers: Layer[];

addPolygon () {
    this.layers = [polygon([[ 43, 3 ], [ 42, 0 ], [ 44, 1 ]])]
}
```

**map.component.html**

```
<div class="map"
  leaflet
  (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
  [leafletOptions]="options"
  [leafletLayers]="layers">
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" name="button" (click)="addPolygon()"></button>
</div>
```

Everything works fine now, the polygon shows up as soon as I click the button. But I need that button to be in another component (`form.component.ts`), so I tried sharing the `addPolygon()` function with a service:

**server.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerService {
  addPolygon: Function;
}
```

I modified `MapComponent` and added the costructor for calling the service

**map.component.ts**

```
export class MapComponent{
  layers: Layer[];

  constructor(private serverService: ServerService){ 
     this.serverService.addPolygon = this.addPolygon 
  };
```

**form.component.ts**

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private serverService: ServerService) { }

  triggerMap() {
      this.serverService.addPolygon()
  }
}
```

But If I bind `triggerMap()` on a button in `form.component.html` the polygon does not get added to the map. The console however says that `addPolygon` in `map.component.ts` is reached.

I tried even using `NgZone`, but it does not make any difference. Any suggestion?

Angular CLI: 6.0.8

Comment: Are you sure both components are modifying/accessing the same instance of ServerService? I've tried several ways to reproduce this but can't. Otherwise, can you provide a standalone GitHub repo that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Sure, here it is a minimal working example: https://github.com/pjoe95/leaflet-problem. I put two buttons below the map so you can instantly check what I am talking about

Comment: There's unresolved conflicts in some of the files. Can you fix those quick and I'll check it out?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what happened there. Now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out your specific issue. It's not really specific to Angular or to Leaflet. I think it's more an artifact of Typescript and Javascript (or maybe something specific to how AOT compiling and TS->JS transpiling works).

Basically, I think the issue is that when you assign the addPolygon function to the service object, the `this` context is changing. So, `this` ends up being the service's `this` and not the component `this`. The result is that a new layers array is created inside I'm assuming the service. You can (sort of) confirm this by doing the following in MapComponent:

```
export class MapComponent {

  layers: Layer[] = [];
  counter = 0;

  constructor(
    private serverService: ServerService,
    private zone: NgZone
  ) {
    this.serverService.addPolygon = this.addPolygon;
  }

  options = {
      layers: [
          tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 18, attribution: '...' })
      ],
      zoom: 5,
      center: latLng(42, 2)
  };


  addPolygon () {
    console.log('I am in addPolygon in MapComponent');
    this.counter++;
    console.log(`Here\'s the counter: ${this.counter}`);

    this.layers = [
        polygon( [[ 43, 3 ], [ 42, 0 ], [ 44, 1 ]] )
    ];
  }

  resetLayers () {
    console.log('Resetting layers');
    console.log(`Here\'s the counter: ${this.counter}`);
    this.layers = [];
  }

}
```

The idea here is that I'm modifying the local `counter` member variable inside of `addPolygon` and then I'm printing it to the console. I also print it to console inside of the `resetLayers` function.

When I click the buttons in the following order: MapComponent, Reset, FormComponent, I get the following output:

```
I am in addPolygon in MapComponent
map.component.ts:36 Here's the counter: 1
map.component.ts:44 Resetting layers
map.component.ts:45 Here's the counter: 1
map.component.ts:34 I am in addPolygon in MapComponent
map.component.ts:36 Here's the counter: NaN
```

MapComponent click increments the counter from 0 to 1 and prints it correctly with a value of 1. Reset click prints the correct counter value of 1. But, FormComponent click prints NaN because it isn't initialized to a value, so incrementing it leaves it as NaN.

To try to nail down which this context is being used for FormComponent's call to addPolygon, I added counters initialized to different values for each of AppComponent, ServerService, and FormComponent. It turns out, it's calling `addPolygon` with the `this` context from `ServerService`.

So, I think the solution to your issue is to either put the layers array inside of ServerServicem or its to use output bindings to communicate events from FormComponent to a component that is the parent of both MapComponent and FormComponent.

Comment: I thought it was a leaflet issue, for now I got it working by placing the buttons in MapComponent but that was a quick fix, I will try to put the layers inside ServerService, thanks!